# Work out Eth price from getAmountsIn method

Tags: web3js, uniswap, arbitrage

I am attempting to create a test arbitrage bot using Uniswap & SushiSwap.

I can successfully get the amount of X tokens I would get for 1 WETH on both dexes. For example:

​

> Uniswap: WETH / USDT   1704.93153
>
> Sushi Swap:  WETH / USDT   1701.745783

To do this I am using the `getAmountsIn` method and passing in 1 WETH.

```
async getBuyPrice() {
    const pathToBuy = await this.routerContract.methods
    // getAmountsIn already includes Uniswap & SushiSwap fees in the calculation
    .getAmountsIn(this.swapAmount, [this.swapTo, this.swapFrom])
        .call();
    // TODO: modify the / 1e12 on a per token basis
    return Math.floor(ethers.utils.parseUnits(pathToBuy[0], this.swapToDecimal) * 100) / 100 / 1e12;
}
```

I then do a simple profit calculation of

```
if (uniswapPrice > sushiswapPrice) {
return Math.abs(sushiswapPrice - uniswapPrice); 
}
```

With these basic calculations I get outputs like:

> estimated profit on trade  WETH/ USDT   3.185746999999992

My issue comes when I want to then take away the TX costs from the profit including gas fees.

I get the gas price back with:

```
let gasPrice;
   await web3.eth.getGasPrice().then((result) => {
    gasPrice = web3.utils.fromWei(result, 'ether');
});
```

> gas price in Eth  0.000000013596475603

However, this gives me the gas price in Eth whereas `getAmountsIn` allows me to calculate the profit in the token I am attempting to swap, for example 3.1 USDT.

Would I then need to convert `WETH/ USDT   3.185746999999992` into Eth and minus TX fees to work out the true profit? I'm quite new to all of this so am unsure.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
const finalProfit = estimatedProfit - gasPrice
```

Yes you need to do this math.